# How to remove space, comma or similar non-ASCI character in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, non-ascii-characters

I want to remove space, commas or similar non-ASCI characters from the string but I didn't.

I tried these but doesn't work.

```
 // my string value = request.ReportName
    Regex.Replace(request.ReportName, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
    Regex.Replace(request.ReportName, @"[^\uxxxx\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty),
```

By the way I tried this as well but doesn't work as well.

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.ReportName));
```

For example: `request.ReportName = "CAption`, For long Text double length long to keep"

I want to do this: CAptionForlongTextdoublelengthlongtokeep. What can I do?
Any idea, please?

Comment: The term is ASCII and of course space and comma are [ASCII characters](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange).

Comment: numbers allowed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace all non-letters:

```
Regex.Replace(request.ReportName, @"[^A-Za-z]+", String.Empty);
```

Another idea for doing the same thing would be

```
Regex MyRegex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string s = MyRegex.Replace(request.ReportName, @"");
```

This might also help you

```
new String(request.ReportName.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c) && Char.IsUpper(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow only alphanumeric characters, below Regex will work.

```
string str = "sffd%^#$%#(*(&$HHFFGF14388>?><>< sfsdf,dsfsdf, fsasdfs,sdff  ,sdfsf-";
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
str = rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

if only alphabets are allowed then you can use the below Regex.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");
```